# How to reuse code which has same functionality but variable name differing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have 3 button which copies content from the text area all three functions are same only the variable name changes, how to use this has a single function instead of three

```
<div class="divclip">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-light btn-sm"
      (click)="copyInputMessageAscii(userinputAscii)"
      id="copyBtnOne">
      {{ toogleCopyBtnAscii ? "Copy" : "Copied" }}
    </button>
</div>
 <div class="divclip">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-light btn-sm"
      (click)="copyInputMessageHex(userinputHex)"
      id="copyBtnTwo"
    >
      {{ toogleCopyBtnHex ? "Copy" : "Copied" }}
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="divclip">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-light btn-sm"
      (click)="copyInputMessageBinary(userinputBinary)"
      id="copyBtnThree"
    >
      {{ toogleCopyBtnBinary ? "Copy" : "Copied" }}
    </button>
  </div>
```

this is component.ts code

```
  copyInputMessageAscii(inputElement) {
    this.toogleCopyBtnAscii = !this.toogleCopyBtnAscii;
    inputElement.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  }

  copyInputMessageHex(inputElement) {
    this.toogleCopyBtnHex = !this.toogleCopyBtnHex;
    inputElement.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  }

  copyInputMessageBinary(inputElement) {
    this.toogleCopyBtnBinary = !this.toogleCopyBtnBinary;
    inputElement.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: It should also help you to know you can also reference (global) variables by using their names as a string (rather than a symbol) like so: `window["myVariableName"]`.

Answer (score 2):

The last three lines are the same for each function. You can refactor the code with a new function like so:

```
  copyInputMessage(inputElement){
    inputElement.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  }
  copyInputMessageAscii(inputElement) {
    this.toogleCopyBtnAscii = !this.toogleCopyBtnAscii;
    copyInputMessage(inputElement);
  }

  copyInputMessageHex(inputElement) {
    this.toogleCopyBtnHex = !this.toogleCopyBtnHex;
    copyInputMessage(inputElement);
  }

  copyInputMessageBinary(inputElement) {
    this.toogleCopyBtnBinary = !this.toogleCopyBtnBinary;
    copyInputMessage(inputElement);
  }
```

Or even better you can do:

```
  copyInputMessage(inputElement,charType) {
    switch(charType) {
      case "hex":
        this.toogleCopyBtnHex = !this.toogleCopyBtnHex;
        break;
      case "binary":
        this.toogleCopyBtnBinary = !this.toogleCopyBtnBinary;
        break;
      default: // assume "ascii"
        this.toogleCopyBtnAscii = !this.toogleCopyBtnAscii;
        break;
    }
    inputElement.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much that helped me shorten my code an learnt something new

Answer (score 0):

try like this, this will not be generic but will reduce code

//Reusable function

```
copyInputMessage(inputElement, inputType) {
        if(inputType === 'binary') {
            this.toogleCopyBtnBinary = !this.toogleCopyBtnBinary;
        }
        if(inputType === 'hex') {
            this.toogleCopyBtnHex = !this.toogleCopyBtnHex;
        }
        if(inputType === 'ascii') {
           this.toogleCopyBtnAscii = !this.toogleCopyBtnAscii;
        }
        this.toogleCopyBtnBinary = !this.toogleCopyBtnBinary;
        inputElement.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
      }
```

// calling function

```
copyInputMessageAscii(userinputAscii, 'binary');
copyInputMessageAscii(userinputAscii, 'hex');
copyInputMessageAscii(userinputAscii, 'ascii');
```

Comment: Extra `toogleCopyBtnBinary ` in there

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch case inside the common function and pass the type.

```
  copyInputMessage(type) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'Ascii':
        this.toogleCopyBtnAscii = !this.toogleCopyBtnAscii;
        break;
      case 'Hex':
        this.toogleCopyBtnHex = !this.toogleCopyBtnHex;
        break;
      case 'Binary':
        this.toogleCopyBtnBinary = !this.toogleCopyBtnBinary;
        break;
    }
    inputElement.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using arrays to track the buttons, user input and user actions.
Below is an example of how you would go about the problem using arrays

In your TS file

```
userInputs = ['Ascii', 'Hex', 'Binary'];
toogleCopyBtn = this.userInputs.reduce((prev, next) => ({prev, [next]: false}), {})
copyInputMessage(userInput) {
  this.toogleCopyBtn[userInput] = !this.toogleCopyBtn[userInput];
  const inputElement = document.querySelector('#inputElement' + userInput) as HTMLInputElement
  inputElement.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
}
```

In your HTML

```
<div *ngFor='let userInput of userInputs; let index = index' class="divclip">
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-light btn-sm"
    (click)="copyInputMessage(userInput)"
    [attr.id]="'copyBtn' + userInput">
    {{ toogleCopyBtn[userInput] ? "Copy" : "Copied" }}
  </button>
</div>

<input *ngFor='let userInput of userInputs' type="text" [attr.id]='"inputElement" + userInput'>
```

See a working example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8qgcma

Comment: Hello Owen if u dont mind can u explain what [attr.id] does or share some reference for that thank you :)

Comment: The syntax [attr.] refers to attribute binding.This is very useful if you want to set the attribute value, using an expression that resolves to a string, or remove the attribute when the expression resolves to null.[About attr. binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding)